# How to find minimum for each unique value for every column grouped by ID in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to find minimum value for each column grouped by ID.

```
#Input data 

df=pd.DataFrame({ 'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'a':range(8), 'b':range(8,0,-1) })

#expected output is the minimum value for each id and column (a, b)
id  a    b  
1   0    5
2   4    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(min)` will do just that.

```py
id  a  b
1   0  5
2   4  1
```

Comment: df.groupby('id',as_index=False).min()

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't realize the 'id' column was not actually in the index, too used to having those down there. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.groupby('id').min()`

Result:

```
    a  b
id      
1   0  5
2   4  1
```